# Как в nginx настроить редиректы в определенной папке

Tags: php, nginx, phalcon

Делаю REST API микро приложение на phalcon

На Apache лежит такой файлик, а на сервере стоит nginx.  Как настроить редиректы в определенной папке?

Это рабочий пример на Apach

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Пробую так не получается

```
location /resource/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1 break;
    }
    }
```

Если вот так то предлагает скачать index.php

```
location /resource/{
        if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /resource/index.php?_url=/$1 break;
        }
    }
```

Подозреваю что нужно как то объединить с

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Настроил так при обращении пишет Access denied. если передать параметр скрипт выполняется и пишет 404 хотя должен был выдать страницу

```
location /resource{
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;


        if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /resource/index.php?_url=/$1 last;
        break;
        }
    }
```

По просьбе все содержимое, при переходе в папку resource #Access denied.#
При запросе resource/index.php выдает правильный результат слово test из кода

```
$app->get('/', function () {
  echo 'test'; 
});
```

Весь конфиг

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    charset utf-8;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;    
    server_name localhost;    
    location / {        
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;      
    }    
    error_page 404 /404.html;    
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /resource{
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;     
        if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /resource/index.php?_url=/$1 last;
        break;
        }
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: а чем не подходит [документация от разработчиков](https://docs.phalconphp.com/ru/latest/reference/nginx.html)?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin нужно в определенной папке настроить редиректы

Comment: т.е. этот самый *phalcon* развёрнут у вас в каталоге `/resource` и всему остальному сайту требуются какие-то иные обработчики?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да микро приложение работает только в той папке, в других метах редиректы не нужны, на оф сайте phalcon  нет настройки на nginix, есть только для apache, там https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/729 уже кто то задавал такой же вопрос, но я пробовал брать от туда конфиги что то не помогло

Comment: тогда, я думаю, имеет смысл привести всё текущее содержимое секции server.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Добавил все

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если что не так поправьте, но заработало вот так

Только в Phalcon немного нужно поменять 
Если раньше работало так:

```
$app->get('/', function () {
  echo 'test'; 
});
```

То сейчас так:

```
$app->get('/page/{page}', function ($page) {
  echo 'test'; 
});
```

*Тоесть без слеша и обязательно должны быть все параметры например /resource/page/2 А вот если /resource/page/ - то не сработает*

Конфиг:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    charset utf-8;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;


    server_name localhost;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

        location @phalcon {
            rewrite ^/resource/(.+)$ /resource/index.php?_url=$1 last;
        }

        location /resource/ {
            index index.php;
            if ($uri !~ ^/resource) {
                rewrite ^/resource(.*)$ /resource$1;
            }
            try_files $uri $uri/ @phalcon;
        }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```